# Recovering data from a dismantled raid 0

Tags: hard-drive, raid, raid-0, qnap

I have a QNAP ts-212 2 bay enclosure, until recently it housed two 3TB drives in a RAID 0.

I have just swapped the drives to two 5TB drives in RAID 0, my backups appear to be missing a couple of files and I would like to recover them, however I'm concerned that each time I've installed a drive in this enclosure it begins by formatting it.

The original drives are untouched.

I do have single drive USB enclosures if they will in any way help.

Is there any way to recover these files without wiping out the data by reinstalling them in the QNAP?

Comment: Your best bet is to take a full disk image of both disks first. Then you can try inserting them and see if that works (with your full image available in case it wipes them). Perhaps someone else will know a more direct method...

Comment: The only way would be to put both drives in.  The reason a single drive is being formatted is because the raid is being rebuilt. Do not put the original drives in, duplicate them, then use the duplicates

Comment: Worth pointing out that RAID 0 has zero fault tolerance.  So hopefully it's not actually RAID 0 your using

Answer (score 2):

While I have not attempted to recover from a broken Raid-0 I have used [this](http://www.r-studio.com/) to recover a raid-5.  Beware of similarly-named software!  One thing nice about it is that it has a demo mode that does everything but actually recover files over 64k--this lets you find out if it's going to do the job before you buy it.

Answer (score 2):

(I don't have one but) [QNAP apparently uses Linux](https://dtidatarecovery.com/server-recovery/san-nas-raid-recovery/qnap-raid-recovery-nas-data-recovery/), and presents as "Software RAID" using standard "mdadm".

DO A BITCOPY BACKUP OF YOUR DISKS BEFORE TRYING THE BELOW - THERE IS ALWAYS RISK WHEN PLAYING WITH BLOCK DEVICES.

This means you should be able to boot a Pendrive Linux distro (Ubuntu Desktop can do this ), and then recreate the RAID array using MDADM with minimal risk of reinitialising the drives.  You can Google authorative information on how to do this, but maybe try something like :

```
   mdadm -A /dev/md0 /dev/sdxX /dev/sdyX 
   mkdir /tmpmountpoint 
   mount /dev/md0 /tmpmountpoint
```

Then copy the desired data from /tmpmountpoint.

Comment: And if this doesn't work, the `0` in `RAID-0` indicates how much data redundancy you have...